# Can I script FlexBuilder without writing an extension?

Tags: eclipse, flexbuilder, textmate

I'd like to script FlexBuilder so that I can run debug or profile without having to switch to FlexBuilder and manually clicking the button (or using the key combo). Is this possible without writing an extension?

To be more specific, this is exactly what I want to do: I want to create a TextMate command that talks to FlexBuilder and makes it run the debug target for the currently selected project. TextMate already has support for interacting with Xcode in this way, and it would be great to be able to do the same with FlexBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

When compiling I use Ant and have full control over that from TextMate, what I want is to be able to launch the *debugger* and the *profiler*. The command line debugger is unusable and there is no other profiler available than the one in FlexBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Since FlexBuilder essentially is an extended version of Eclipse, any tools/scripts for doing the same in Eclipse should work for FlexBuilder aswell. I couldn't find any tools like this googling it, have you considered doing away with FlexBuilder completely, there are plenty of guides for using the mxmlc (or fcsh) compilers directly from your editor.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is a plugin like this for Eclipse however if not you can write one as it should be easy.

If the specific command that you want to call shows up in **Windows/Preferences** - **General/Keys**, you can create a plugin that takes commands from TextMate (I do not know what protocol TextMate uses, socket or something else) and executed the specific action that is associated with the command that also appears in preferences.

Comment: ...yes, so much is obvious, but HOW?